# Помогите удалить класс js

Tags: javascript

Переделываю модальное окно. Есть одна кнопка с одним классом и 4 кнопки с другим классом, которые открывают одно и тоже модальное окно и добавляют себе новый класс.  Открытие модального окна и присвоение класса проходит нормально. Но когда пытаюсь закрыть модалку, то модалка закрывается, а класс не удаляется. Возникает конфликток между этими строчками
  `if (target.className == 'popup-close') {
   target.classList.remove('more-splash');`
Как мне при нажатии на кнопку закрыть (close) найти кнопку с присвоенным классом и удалить его.

```
let overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay'),
close = document.querySelector('.popup-close');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let target = event.target;

    if (target.className == 'description-btn' || target.className == 'more') 
    {
        target.classList.add('more-splash');
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }

    if (target.className == 'popup-close') {

    target.classList.remove('more-splash');
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflow = '';
    }
```

});

https://codepen.io/Pavlenkovik/pen/qyGopo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, так:
`document.getElementsByClassName('more-splash')[0].classList.remove('more-splash')`.
У Вас этот класс вешается не на кнопку, а на div по которому кликнули, следовательно при нажатии на Close он не может удалиться, поскольку его попросту нет.

Правленный пример:

```js
let overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay'),
  description = document.querySelectorAll('.description-btn'),
  more = document.querySelector('.more'),
  close = document.querySelector('.popup-close');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let target = event.target;

  if (target.className == 'description-btn' || target.className == 'more') {
    target.classList.add('more-splash');
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    console.dir(target);
    console.log(target.className);
    console.log(target.classList);

  }

  if (target.className == 'popup-close') {
    document.getElementsByClassName('more-splash')[0].classList.remove('more-splash');
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflow = '';
  }
});
```

```css
.content .info-tabcontent .description-btn {
  width: 180px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 43px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #c78030;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #c78030;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 3;
}

.overlay .popup {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  left: 50%;
  top: 150px;
  width: 752px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.overlay .popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: -35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.overlay .popup-title {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 71px;
  line-height: 71px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #c78030;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container" id="about">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="info-header">
        <div class="info-header-tab"></div>
        <div class="info-header-tab"></div>
        <div class="info-header-tab"></div>
        <div class="info-header-tab"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="info-tabcontent fade">
        <div class="description">
          <div class="description-title"></div>
          <div class="description-text">
          </div>
          <div class="description-btn">
            Узнать подробнее
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="photo">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="info-tabcontent fade">
        <div class="description">
          <div class="description-title"></div>
          <div class="description-text"></div>
          <div class="description-btn">
            Узнать подробнее
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="photo">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="info-tabcontent fade">
        <div class="description">
          <div class="description-title"></div>
          <div class="description-text"></div>
          <div class="description-btn">
            Узнать подробнее
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="photo">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="info-tabcontent fade">
        <div class="description">
          <div class="description-title"></div>
          <div class="description-text"></div>
          <div class="description-btn">
            Узнать подробнее
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="photo">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="more"> Узнать больше</button>



  </div>

</div>
<div class="overlay fade">
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-close">&times;
    </div>
    <div class="popup-title">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, так  и знал, что что-то простое, но в упор ответа не видел.

Comment: заменил `querySelector` на `getElementsByClassName` - он работает быстрее.